# Handling Session for multiple controller in spring boot

Tags: java, angular, session, spring-boot

I am beginner in java. I want to use session object in different controllers and trying to access them from UI(which is written in angular4).

My entity class is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_MASTER")
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserMaster {

    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private long empId;

    @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
    private String empName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
    @JsonBackReference(value="user-role")
    private RoleMaster roleMaster;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="MOBILE")
    private long mobile;

    @Column(name="DESIGNATION")
    private String designation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor")
    private List<UserMaster> trainee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MENTOR_ID",referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")
    private UserMaster mentor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userMaster")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<NotificationMaster> notificationMaster;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userMaster")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<UserTracks> userTracks;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="USER_MODULES",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID",referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MODULE_ID",referencedColumnName="MODULE_ID")})
    private List<ModulesMaster> modulesMaster;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="USER_MODULES",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID",referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="LINK_ID",referencedColumnName="LINK_ID")})
    private List<LinksMaster> linksMaster;

    public long getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(long empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public RoleMaster getRoleMaster() {
        return roleMaster;
    }

    public void setRoleMaster(RoleMaster roleMaster) {
        this.roleMaster = roleMaster;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public long getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(long mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public List<UserMaster> getTrainee() {
        return trainee;
    }

    public void setTrainee(List<UserMaster> trainee) {
        this.trainee = trainee;
    }

    public UserMaster getMentor() {
        return mentor;
    }

    public void setMentor(UserMaster mentor) {
        this.mentor = mentor;
    }

    public List<NotificationMaster> getNotificationMaster() {
        return notificationMaster;
    }

    public void setNotificationMaster(List<NotificationMaster> notificationMaster) {
        this.notificationMaster = notificationMaster;
    }

    public List<UserTracks> getUserTracks() {
        return userTracks;
    }

    public void setUserTracks(List<UserTracks> userTracks) {
        this.userTracks = userTracks;
    }

    public List<ModulesMaster> getModulesDetails() {
        return modulesMaster;
    }

    public void setModulesDetails(List<ModulesMaster> modulesMaster) {
        this.modulesMaster = modulesMaster;
    }

    public List<LinksMaster> getLinksDetails() {
        return linksMaster;
    }

    public void setLinksDetails(List<LinksMaster> linksMaster) {
        this.linksMaster = linksMaster;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserMaster [empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName
                + ", password=" + password + ", emailId=" + emailId
                + ", mobile=" + mobile + "]";
    }

}
```

Now, in one controller I am setting session attribute.
Code is:

```
package com.capgemini.dilse.domain.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.capgemini.dilse.domain.DTO.loginDTO;
import com.capgemini.dilse.domain.entity.UserMaster;
import com.capgemini.dilse.domain.exception.UserException;
import com.capgemini.dilse.domain.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/1")
public class SessionController2 {

    @Autowired
    private UserMaster userMaster;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService; 

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @RequestMapping("/2")
    public void set(){
        loginDTO loginDTO = new loginDTO();
        loginDTO.setEmpId(1);
        loginDTO.setPassword("123");
        try {
            userMaster=userService.login(loginDTO);
            //if(userMaster2!=null){
                //userMaster=userMaster2;
                //userMaster.setEmpName(userMaster.getEmpName());
                session.setAttribute("user", userMaster);
            //}else{
                //userMaster=null;
            //}
        } catch (UserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/3")
    public void get(){
        System.out.println("name is "+userMaster.getEmpName());
    }
}
```

Now in second controller I am trying to get the value of the attribute it is returning null when I hit from UI.

Second controller code is:

```
package com.capgemini.dilse.domain.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.capgemini.dilse.domain.entity.UserMaster;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/2")
public class SessionController1 {

    @Autowired
    private UserMaster userMaster;

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @RequestMapping("/3")
    public void get(){
        System.out.println("user is "+session.getAttribute("user"));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/4")
    public void sessionTimeout(){
        session.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Please help me in solving this. Thanks in advance.

If the code is right then please tell me how should I send request from UI.

Comment: I think you're designing micro services with Spring boot. If that's the case, then you should not think on stateful services because it's not the nature of the services. I think you have a design problem. It would be better to explain the real issue and why you think using session on server side is the solution.

Comment: Actually I need that my application should maintain session accordingly w.r.t. logged in users.
That's why I need to maintain session.
And can you please tell me what do you mean by stateful services. #Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: Logged user != session alive. You can always expose your services and receive a parameter to identify the user e.g. userid. You should focus on how to secure these services so only your client application may consume it. You may/want to do some research about it and start with JWT and OAuth2.